# Read query string paramter from Image Url [asp.net]

Tags: asp.net, query-string, imageurl

I have created a dynamic image using `Generic Handler[.ashx]` and then assigning the same to the Image on my user control from code behind.

```
string capt = //some random logic value.
imgCaptcha.ImageUrl = "~/BO/term.ashx?param=" + capt;
```

Now on some button event on same usercontrol, I want to read the query parameter of the `ImageUrl`

```
 protected void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     //something like this
     string param = Request.QueryString["param"]

 }
```

But Request.`QueryString` wont give me anything as the usercontrol is added on some `.aspx` page
so Request path will be the same `.aspx` page which do not have the query parameters.

But `imgCaptcha.ImageUrl` give me some path which is `~/BO/term.ashx?param=123456`.

**Now I want to read this information using some .Net standard class.
Is there anything which will solve my query?**

*Note : I am not much interested in using string methods.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can generate uri and retrieve query string parameters however string split is better:

```
 Uri uri = new System.Uri(Page.Request.Url, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(Image1.ImageUrl));
 var parameters = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query);
 string value = parameters["param"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. You you can read it only from the `term.ashx`. So you have to parse the `ImageURL` parameter or save the parameter value somewhere.

For example you can save it in the `ViewState`:

```
string capt = //some random logic value.
ViewState["imgCaptchaParameter"] = capt;
imgCaptcha.ImageUrl = "~/BO/term.ashx?param=" + capt;
```

And use it like this inside the method:

```
protected void btnVerify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //something like this
    string param = ViewState["imgCaptchaParameter"].ToString();
}
```